# Recyclerview Child Items

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

When I try to update a child item view (e.g. set the typeface of the textview inside that child view to bold), the invisible child item also got updated. For example there is 8 items inside my recyclerview, when I updated first child item view, the 7th child item view also updated. How to prevent this?

Comment: have you added  RecyclerView.ViewHolder into your adapter?

Comment: @SandeepKharat Yes

Comment: Can you share your adapter code and how the update function work please ?

Answer (score 0):

on your onBindViewHolder(), you just need to update specified item. Then it will not effect to another item in recyclerview

Check

```
// the first item in the list
if(position == 0) {
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what are you trying to say. The view is updated when some events occured. So if do this in onBindViewHolder, the items is set to BOLD before events occurred. Isn't it?

Comment: No, when some event occured, and you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the view. Method `onBindViewHolder()` will run for all item in the `recyclerview`. You if you just want to update the first item (or another) you need to check it in `onBindViewHolder()` `position `agurment. It's position of your item in the list

Comment: Not sure why, but I just set all textview to tyface to normal inside onBindViewHolder. Then only change it to BOLD when event occured. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

In `RecyclerView` 1st Item is recycled and used as the 7th Item.

So If there is a specific condition that you want to set the typeface then set typeface according to condition

```
if(condition){
textview.setTypeFace(<font1>);
}else{
textview.setTypeFace(<font2>);
}
```

if it is constant then set it when ur initalizing th view for the very first time.

Thanks